# ST_Intersection + ST_Difference + not overlapping Polygons

Tags: postgis, overlapping-features, st-intersects, st-difference

I have a PostGIS table with some overlapping polygon and need a PostGIS view where no polygon is overlapping and the data is aggregated (like in the picture).

[image]

With a Union of ST_Intersection() and ST_Difference() I get the upper 3 polygons, but then I'm missing the Polygons with no overlap?

```
SELECT ST_Intersection(a.geometry, b.geometry), a.color||','||b.color as color
FROM mytable a, mytable b 
WHERE a.fid < b.fid AND ST_INTERSECTS(a.geometry, b.geometry)
UNION
SELECT ST_Difference(a.geometry, b.geometry), a.color as color
FROM mytable a, mytable b
WHERE a.fid < b.fid AND ST_INTERSECTS(a.geometry, b.geometry)
```

How do I include the polygons with no overlap?
Is there maybe an easier solution for my problem, like a split/aggregate function?

Comment: note that your approach is only working as expected for no more than two polygons overlapping *as a pair* (a 3rd polygon overlapping any of the two, or both, will lead to partial duplication).

Comment: Is there a way to deal with multiple overlapping polygons?

Comment: the key for handling multiple overlaps, as well as non-intersection, is to pass a union of *all intersecting* geometries (other than the one to test against) to the function(s); as you might expect, this is computational expensive, and the transition of other column values requires another join, since the union can't keep them. this can also be done recursively, or, possibly best, within a custom (PL/pgSQL) function.

Comment: There is support for many overlap cases in the PostGIS Addons https://github.com/pedrogit/postgisaddons/blob/master/postgis_addons.sql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a left join on the two tables and keep the rows from A that have not intersections in B

```sql
SELECT a.geometry, a.color as color
FROM mytable a
 LEFT JOIN mytable b ON ST_INTERSECTS(a.geometry, b.geometry)
WHERE b.fid IS NULL
```

Keeping your approach, you would add this query to the list of unions. To make it more efficient, you should not use `UNION` but `UNION ALL` instead (it does not try to remove duplicates, so you save a lot of geometry comparisons). At last, you may want to do the left join between A and B in a CTE, and apply the 3 sub-query on the CTE (no need to check 3 times for the intersections)

Comment: Thanks, that did exactly what I wanted. Plus I do the left join between A and B in a CTE now and its faster, thx for the hint.